# Error On PDO Login System

Tags: php

Im changing all my code from mysql to PDO but im having a little trouble. I read alot of information on here plus tutorial from nettus but still cant figure out why my code isn't working.

Below is login.php PHP when i press login it should you open my User class and start login.

```
<?php

    require_once('../global.php');
    require_once('../assets/header.php');
    if (isLogged())
    {
        header("Location: $website_domain");
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        if(empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            $password == "";
        }
        else
        {
            $password = md5($_POST['password'].$_POST['username']);
        }

        $object = new User();
        $object->Login($username,$password);

    }

?>
```

this is the error im receiving: 
`Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/astonish/public_html/labs.site.com/lock/includes/classes/user.class.php on line 32`

If you need to see my User class please ask, I dont want to fill this up with code when all you guys need to see is the error.

User.class.php

```
<?php

    require_once('connection.php');

    // new data
    $ip    = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $hour  = date('h');
    $month = date('m');
    $date  = dateTime();

    class User
    {
        private $db;
        public function _construct() 
        {
            $this->db = new Connection();
            $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect(); 
        }

        public function Login($name, $pass) 
        {
            if(empty($name))
            {
                echo "Please input a username";
            }
            elseif(empty($pass))
            {
                echo "Please input a password";
            }
            elseif(!empty($name) && !empty($pass))
            {
                $st = $this->db->prepare("select * from users where username=? and password=?");
                $st->bindParam(1, $name);
                $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
                $st->execute();

                if($st->rowCount() == "1")
                {

                    // Delete failed attempts
                    $st = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM failedLogins WHERE ip = :ip');
                    $st->bindParam(':ip', $ip); // this time, we'll use the bindParam method
                    $st->execute();

                    // Get status of user
                    $result = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $result->status;

                    if ($fetch['status']==1)
                    {
                        $error = 'Your account is pending email.';
                    }
                    else if ($fetch['status']==2)
                    {
                        $_SESSION['main'] = md5(sha1($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].$fetch['id']));
                        $_SESSION['uid'] = base64_encode($fetch['id']);

                        header("Location: $website_domain");
                        exit;
                    }
                    else if ($fetch['status']==5)
                    {
                        $error = 'Your account is inactive or was denied.';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $error = 'Invalid account status.';
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {   
                $st = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `failedLogins` (ip,hour,month,date) VALUES (:ip,:hour,:month,:date)");
                $st->execute(array(':ip'=>$ip, ':hour'=>$hour, ':month'=>$month, ':date'=>$date));

                echo  'The username or password entered is invalid.';
            }
        }

    }

?>
```

connection.php

```
class Connection 
    {
        public function dbConnect() 
        {
            return new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=astonish_viral", $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
            /*try 
            {
                $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=astonish_viral", $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
                echo 'Connected to database';
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }*/
        }
    }
```

New errors:
Now getting the errors below

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in /home/astonish/public_html/labs.site.com/lock/includes/classes/connection.php:12 Stack trace: #0 /home/astonish/public_html/labs.site.com/lock/includes/classes/connection.php(12): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', NULL, NULL) #1 /home/astonish/public_html/labs.site.com/lock/includes/classes/user.class.php(17): Connection->dbConnect() #2 /home/astonish/public_html/labs.site.com/lock/account/login.php(23): User->__construct() #3 {main} thrown in /home/astonish/public_html/labs.site.com/lock/includes/classes/connection.php on line 12
```

Comment: In order to debug an error, one must see the file in which the error appears.

Comment: We need to see `user.class.php` file.

Comment: Where do you initialize  $mysql_user, $mysql_pass?

Comment: on connection that php i just remove from code

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your `PDO` object (assuming you've created one) is not in scope within your `User::Login()` method.

Taking some assumptions here but lets say you create your `PDO` object in `global.php`, eg

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host...');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

You should register this within your `User` class, eg

```
class User {
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    // etc
```

Then you can use this object within the `User` methods, eg

```
public function Login($username, $password) {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT ... ');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password
    ));

    // etc
}
```

When you create your `User` class, pass the `PDO` instance via the constructor

```
$object = new User($pdo); // pass $pdo object created in global.php
$object->Login($username, $password);
```

### Update

It seems you're simply missing the `$this->` prefix on this line

```
// Delete failed attempts
$st = $db->prepare(...
```

Should be

```
$st = $this->db->prepare(...
```

### Addendum

I don't think you should be creating a connection every time you instantiate your `User` class. Instead, you should create the connection independently and inject it via the constructor. This way, you can re-use the `PDO` object.

Also, your `Connection` class seems redundant. `PDO` is a great class to work with without wrapping it in abstraction layers if you're only supporting one type of database.

Comment: Although I find it funny. What is the sense of assuming syntax errors before seeing the code?

Comment: @hek2mgl It's fairly obvious from the error message. The OP probably had instances of `mysql_query()` littered throughout their code which will happily work on the last made connection without having to pass the actual resource around. Swapping this out for `$pdo->prepare()` isn't going to work when the `PDO` instance is not in scope and will result in the *Call to a member function on a non-object* error

Comment: I'm with you of course, but you are a really fast debugger! :) too fast? we'll see. :)

Comment: It's called black-box debugging? :D

Comment: yeah i had all mysql queries im switching from mysql to PDO

Answer (score 1):

Thats a typo you misspelled your constructor. As you misspelled the method name, 'your' constructor will never get called and so $this->db will never get initialized.

You have two options to define a constructor in PHP:

```
public function __construct()
```

Note that **two** underscores are required to work as a constructor. Another option you have is to name the constructor method like the class

```
public function User()
```

*Note, I would advice the first style, as you won't have to change the constructors name if you change the class name*

---

There is another syntax error in your code. Replace line 41 of User.php for

```
$st = $this->$db->prepare('DELETE FROM failedLogins WHERE ip = :ip');
```

(You where missing the `$this`)

---

You've posted another error in your question's update. Where are you defining `$mysql_user`, `$mysql_pass` in Connection class?

Comment: +1 Though they're also missing a `$this->` prefix for one of the `$db` calls (noted in my answer)

Comment: i made all the changes you guys said and im getting whole new errors ill figure them out though, thanks guys

Comment: `public function User()` should not be used: it was the PHP4-style. See last paragraph of http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php .

Comment: I wouldn't use it too. Also it won't work anyway when you are above 5.3.3 and using namespaces

Comment: @hek2mgl that must be it im on 5.3.3 i dont really know how to use i was following a tutorial on how to set this up.